# Include headers of 3rd party package

Tags: cmake, compilation, point-cloud-library

For a c++ project I am trying to include a package as a 3rd party package: PCL (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/pcl-1.10.0).

But I am having trouble including it into the project's cmake. The package is located in a `thirdparty` folder. I am currently including it using `add_subdirectory(thirdparty/pcl)` which seems to work until I try to compile my project's files. They cannot compile because the header files are not found, I tried to do like in the documentation and add

```
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

but this does not help.

Do you know how I should proceed?

EDIT: this how I then include the packages, `target_link_libraries(program ${PCL_LIBRARIES} pcl_visualization)`. It isn't working since  `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` is empty.

Comment: just `target_link_libraries` to whichever targets you want to link to.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but I tried ```target_link_libraries(program ${PCL_LIBRARIES} pcl_visualization)```. It isn't working since  ```${PCL_LIBRARIES}``` is empty

Comment: yes. you'd have to link to each target whose interface your library depends on (you could technically skimp out on specifying those that are transitively linked)